# TinyScrollbar not working on iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinyscrollbar

TinyScrollbar on their website has written in features that it supports Touch Devices.

**Does it supports ?**

Even their examples on their website is not scrollable on safari, Iphone 5S.
I dont know where i am wrong. Even i'm, but their examples are also not working on safari iphone.

For my web page i have used following code ..

```
var scrollbar = $('#scrollable').tinyscrollbar({thumbSizeMin : 0,wheelLock : false,   touchLock : false});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="scrollable" class="filtercon specialtop">
    <div class="scrollbar"><div class="track"><div class="thumb"><div class="end"></div></div></div></div>
    <div class="viewport">
         <div class="overview">
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I confirm, TinyScrollBar exemples on their website don't work either on my iPhone

Comment: @EdenSource Is there any configuration for that? or simply it dont works but they have mentioned.

Comment: After reading their doc, it doesn't seem there is any special configuration for devices. I would believe that this is a bug. I tryed on both safari & Chrome, nothing happend, only the link "scroll the content to x px".

Comment: Strange behaviour. I tried to create a Fiddle, and it is working on phone o_O https://jsfiddle.net/vw0ogsca/. it might be a bad update (test is with v1.81)

Comment: The version you tried is old one i think

Comment: I found it they have bug in their api, i got it fixed

Comment: A typo in  `drag` instead of function _drag

Comment: Ok, great job. Could you please post the solution as answer for more visibility